# Designing a contacts database in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005, database-design

I think this is a common thing to do... you have a database server, and you want to store customer contact information in it.

You need the person's name, their address, phone, etc.

What are best practices for storing addresses and phones? Assuming OLTP...

Multiple people may have the same phone number (such as wife and husband, or mother and daughter).

Multiple people share a household.

I read this: http://sqlcat.com/sqlcat/b/whitepapers/archive/2008/09/03/best-practices-for-semantic-data-modeling-for-performance-and-scalability.aspx

And that will work fine for the specific model mentioned, but I don't see how this model can be optimized short of denormalizing.

Ex:

- Person table = person id, first name, last name, etc...
- Address table = address id, address line 1, etc..
- Phone table = phone id, phone number, etc...

So if I designed it like that whitepaper suggests, I'd have a `personid` in my `address` table and in my `phone` table. However, since multiple people may share the same address, that isn't feasible. One person may have multiple addresses or even no addresses. So it seems I'll need a person -> address mapping table as well as a mapping table for the phones, otherwise I'll denormalize both of those tables and let there be some duplicates in the unusual case of two people who share the same phone / address.

Anyway, my point in asking this question is because it seems difficult to find a 'best practices' for this type of thing, yet it seems like the type of thing which would come up in just about any type of application or database.

Comment: Most contact databases don't make an effort to share one address or phone number among multiple people. It's a lot of work for the user to enter this complex related data, anyway--usually if two people share a number, you just enter the number twice and be done with it. May I suggest that you read [A Universal Person and Organization Data Model](http://www.tdan.com/view-articles/5014/) for some ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Normalizing addresses and phone numbers in a one-to-many relationship where a `Contact` may have many related `Phone` or `Address` entities makes perfect sense.

However, there is no need to normalize addresses and phone numbers in a many-to-many relationship in a contacts database, because those are not entities you have any interest in working with by themselves, on their own merits as unique entities. In fact, I would say that in your situation, normalizing them to that level is not a good design.

If you were modeling a business in real estate, rentals, or phone service, where you cared about properties and phone numbers even when no person was associated with them, then it could make sense to model them to this level. It is more work for someone to avoid duplicate addresses and phone numbers in the many-to-many design than it is for them to just enter the address again, and there is no real benefit to avoiding these duplicates. Plus, you'll end up with duplicates anyway (at least for addresses, unless you scrub them all real-time using post office routines), so who is going to go through and match up '123 Ascot Wy #5' to '123 Ascot Way Apt 5'? What value is there in that?

The usual reason for normalizing this deep doesn't apply. Let's say that you do create a `PhoneNumber` table and the `PersonPhoneNumber` table needed for the many-to-many relationship. You have three people using the same phone number and they are all properly linked to it. Now, one of them calls you up and tells you that he is changing his phone number. Are you **sure** you want to change the actual `PhoneNumber` record and update the numbers of the other two folks at the same time? What if they aren't moving with him? Soon you will find that your data is screwed up. You may as well normalize first names to the `FirstName` table and last names to the `LastName` table! Then when "Joey" grows up and changes his name to "Joe", all the other Joeys will get an automatic upgrade. But whoops... "Joe" already exists, as does the phone number that you are changing one of the three people above to... what an awful mess.

For another thing, will you use `PhoneID` as a surrogate key for the phone number? But phone numbers are one of the few things that actually are good as natural keys, they almost even demand being used as natural keys. Then your `Phone` table becomes meaningless because it doesn't encode any additional information about that phone number. It would just be a list of phone numbers, *which are already present in the referencing table*. Don't use a `Phone` table like that. If you want to find out whether two people share the same phone number, you just join on or group by the column! In my mind it approaches silliness to have a layer of abstraction where a phone number is linked to a monotonically-increasing `PhoneID`.

If you read [A Universal Person and Organization Model](http://www.tdan.com/view-articles/5014/) you will see the perspective that phone numbers and addresses in fact aren't entities that need modeling to the level of a many-to-many relationship--they are more like "intelligent locators" that route messages to recipients. Why on earth would you force three different people's locator (a.k.a. phone number) to be identical? The locator helps to locate the *person*, not the physical phone that rings. You couldn't care less about the phone or who else might answer--you only care about the fact that once answered, the person of interest could possibly be reached.

Comment: Downvoters: please comment! I will not revenge downvote you. It would simply help me improve the quality of my answer to address any useful criticism.

Comment: Thanks, you have some good ideas. There should not be a need to search the phone table for a specific number since I don't really care about the numbers themselves, just the people and what numbers they have assigned to them. A 'person phone' table may fit the bill. As for addresses though, they also have phone numbers, in cases where business information is stored, there may not be a person per se, but a business entity and an address. The address would need to have a phone number associated, however I see no need to store those phone numbers in the same place as person phone numbers. Thanks!

Comment: @ErikE I know its an old question / answer but I would like to +1 because of the well thought out clear, concise and well written answer.

Answer (score 1):

Normalize.

Normalize until it hurts.

Normalize again until it is excruciating.

Then tune your queries; design your indices; and measure your performance; if at that point you have no other options, denormalize the bare minimum to meet performance options.

Remember that every denormalization that speeds performance on one query, by its nature degrades performance on (almost) every operation on tat table set. Only keep the denormalizaiton if measurement actually shows a noticeable performance improvement.

Remember that the more you normalize the smaller your indices are; the more index rows sit in cache, and the faster your database performs. Yes, a lot of very small tables get created - they are permanently in cache and thus almost free to access.

Comment: We've all heard "normalize until it hurts, denormalize until it works," but I think this truism without context is not very useful to a beginner--especially when said beginner has provided an actual use case/real-world scenario where he needs specific advice. After reading my answer, do you really think that phone numbers should be "normalized" to the level the OP is suggesting? Do you really think a `Person` table should have `FirstNameID` and `LastNameID` as FKs to a `Name` table? That would certainly be excruciating--and almost certainly **wrong**. So, imho, this is not good advice.

Comment: @ErikE: What!? OP is not suggesting anything of the sort. Where do you get that.

Comment: He is suggesting normalizing phone numbers and addresses, which I likened in my answer to normalizing names. You said, "normalize until it is excruciating" and I presented to you some excruciating normalization (FirstName and LastName) and asked if that really made sense to you. I wasn't trying to say the OP suggested this level of normalization, but that *you* had, implicitly.